# PHP Create Multilayer array of years and months

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to create a simple front end to a MySQL database, which will display tables separated into directories of years and months.

What I would like to have is an array of years, with each year having a sub array of months, and each month having a sub array of table names which has that year and month in its date column.

Something like:

> 2017 {
>   
>     01 {
>   
>         Table01
>   
>         Table02
>   
>     }
>   
>     02 {
>   
>         Table03
>   
>         Table04
>   
>     }
>   
> }

What is the best way to create this structure of array? I don't have much experience with multilevel arrays.

I have already got a simple array of only the years found in the MySQL tables, so I just need to add the months to that and then add the table names after.

Each table in MySQL is named _ProductID, the ID being a six digit number. It contains a list of all orders of that product for a given month. So for January 2017 the ID/Table Name might be _123456, but for February it would be _123457.

Each table does have an Ordered_On column with the date format YYYY-MM-DD, so I am selecting the years with a foreach statement running through all tables:

```
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $year = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT ORDERED_ON FROM $table LIMIT 1")
    ->fetch_array()[0];

    if(!in_array(explode('-', $year)[0], $years, true)) {
        array_push($years, explode('-', $year)[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us some informations about your tables in mysql. And how you actually retrieve them.

Comment: You must show us your code.

Comment: I've added some more information about the tables and how I have created the array of only relevant years, if that is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out how to achieve what I wanted. I first ran a mysqli_query to gather all table names and add them to an array and then I used a foreach loop to run through each table and add it to the overall dates array:

```
$structure = [];

foreach($wowcherTables as $tableName) { 
    $redeemed = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT Redeemed_At FROM wowcher.$tableName LIMIT 1")
                ->fetch_array()[0];

    $year = explode('-', $redeemed)[0];
    $month = explode('-', $redeemed)[1];

    $structure[$year][$month] = array();
}
```

This first foreach statement gets the year and month from the first row of each table and creates those as layers within the $structure array.

I then had to do an identical foreach statement to add each table name to the array using array_push, because for some reason when I just had the array_push in the single foreach only one table name would be added to each month.

```
foreach($wowcherTables as $tableName) { 
    $redeemed = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT Redeemed_At FROM wowcher.$tableName LIMIT 1")
                ->fetch_array()[0];

    $year = explode('-', $redeemed)[0];
    $month = explode('-', $redeemed)[1];

    array_push($structure[$year][$month], $tableName);
}
```

If someone could explain to me the reason for this happening and a more efficient way to add the tables, it would be very useful, as having two identical foreach statements seems excessive and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of "strtotime", it's an incredibly powerful function inside PHP. It allows you to convert a date and manipulate it with the date() function, as seen below.
On top of that, PHP associative arrays are incredibly easy to create on the fly. Since you're only adding one element at a time, there's no real need for an array_push.

```
foreach($tables as $table) {
   $year = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT ORDERED_ON FROM $table LIMIT 1")
->fetch_array()[0];

    $year = date("Y",strtotime($year));
    $month = date("m",strtotime($year));

    $years[$year][$month][] = $table;
}
```

I hope this helps.